# ssh ipv6 address in R ssh package

Tags: r, ssh

How do I ssh ipv6 address in R ssh package

```
library(ssh)

# works
session <- ssh_connect("user@10.1.1.0")

# gives error
session <- ssh_connect("user@24:022f:0313:112:0::2")
```

> Error in parse_host(host, default_port = 22) : 
>         host string contains multiple ':' characters

Comment: It appears that it does not support ipv6 addressing. You might try defining that ipv6 address in your `hosts` file and using the name, but I don't know that that will definitely work. You could always file a [new issue](https://github.com/ropensci/ssh/issues) in the repo to see if the devs/maintainers are willing to bake in support.

Comment: Is there any workaround other than defining host file?

Comment: If you look at [the source of that error message](https://github.com/ropensci/ssh/blob/master/R/connect.R#L80), it's hard-coded to look for a single colon, indicating the port number. You can try `debugonce(ssh::parse_host)`, then once `x <- strsplit(...)` is run, override the value of `x` to be length 1, and then let the function continue. It's not a fix, it's a hack, but it might get you started. If it works, I suggest you mention that in a new issue at github.

Comment: If you install [this fork](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ssh) of the package (`devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/ssh"`) it adds support for IPv6 by enabling specifying the components separately. So you can do `ssh_connect("2405:0200:0313:112:41::42", "user")` in your example. I'm not going to PR it as Jeroen/rOpenSci folks will likely have their own ideas for how to best solve this. If you can't install source compiled packages on your system, you'll have to wait for them to update the package and get it on CRAN.

Comment: It appears the package does not honor `~/.ssh/config` so that possible workaround (which does not. require `root` privileges) is also unavailable. The direct `.Call()` suggested in the answer is likely the only temporary solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't install source packages, one *super hacky* way to do this is to call the C function `ssh_connect()` calls directly:

```
.Call(
  ssh:::C_start_session, "2405:0200:0313:112:41::42", 22, "user", NULL, ssh:::askpass, FALSE
)
```

That C interface is *highly* unlikely to change so it *should* be a pretty safe hack until the package eventually supports IPv6.

For those that stumble on this before the rOpenSci folks make any changes, the fork : https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ssh : also adds support for using a local SSH config file. Which means you can add a `Host` entry for IPv6 addresses (along with any other config options) and they'll be looked up.

i.e. if one has:

```
Host awickedcoolhost
  User boringusername
  Hostname ::1
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  Port 22222
```

in `~/.ssh/config`, one can (with the fork) do:

```
ssh_connect("awickedcoolhost", config="~/.ssh/config")
```

and all the overrides in that entry should work.

Comment: Did you try substituting `ssh:::askpass` with the password (as a string)? I also have no idea what you mean by the library comment since I'm not telling you to use the thing I wrote.

Comment: Also, FWIW, hardcoding passwords in scripts is super-dangerous. That, combined with using IP addresses instead of hostnames makes this super-fragile code and a playground for any attacker that randomly or deliberately gets access to this system. You should check with your IT/infosec department on just how many rules you're breaking.

Comment: Hopefully the smileys will work on your IT auditors as well when they come-a-calling :-)

Comment: Thats fine . Its for our internal system testing . you dont have to worry about that. Anyways that you for workaround.